# Set Path of node_modules folder in Browserify

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, browserify

My Browserify ("^11.2.0") can't find my node_modules folder , because he is trying to find in the incorrect folder \ui\src\app, the correct it's \ui\node_modules.

> [15:37:18] Browserify Error { [Error: Cannot find module
>   'angular-spectrum-colorpicker/node_modules/spectrum-colorpicker/spectrum.js'
>   from 'C:\Workarea\helloworld\ui\src\app']

How I can set in Browserify the correct path of my node_modules folder?